# Teradata MERGE yielding no results when executed through SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, teradata, sql-merge

I'm attempting to use python with sqlalchemy to download some data, create a temporary staging table on a Teradata Server, then MERGEing that table into another table which I've created to permanently store this data. I'm using `sql = slqalchemy.text(merge)` and `td_engine.execute(sql)` where `merge` is a string similar to the below:

```
MERGE INTO perm_table as p
USING temp_table as t
ON p.Id = t.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET col1 = t.col1,
col2 = t.col2,
...
col50 = t.col50
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (col1,
col2,
...
col50)
VALUES (t.col1,
t.col2,
...
t.col50)
```

The script runs all the way to the end without error and the SQL executes properly through Teradata Studio, but for some reason the table won't update when I execute it through SQLAlchemy. However, I've also run different SQL expressions, like the insert that populated `perm_table` from the same python script and it worked fine. Maybe there's something specific to the MERGE and SQLAlchemy combo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the engine directly, without using a transaction, you're probably (barring unseen configuration on your part) relying on SQLAlchemy's version of [autocommit](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit), which works by detecting data changing operations such as INSERTs etc. Possibly MERGE is not one of the detected operations. Try

```
sql = sqlalchemy.text(merge).execution_options(autocommit=True)
td_engine.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Yep. Works perfectly.