# sqlalchemy vs pgadmin query tool: WITH INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am stuck on a very simple problem. I run sql script as follows:

```
WITH r AS ( SELECT m.*, ROW_NUMBER() 
    OVER (PARTITION BY word ORDER BY freq DESC) AS rn FROM raw_words AS m)
INSERT INTO preprocessed_words(word, pos, lemma, freq) 
    SELECT r.word, r.pos, r.lemma, r.freq FROM r where r.rn=1
```

This basically removes duplicate rows and saves data to another table. Then I run it in pgAdmin 4 with query tool, my table `preprocess_words` is populated successfully. However, then I try to run in script like:

```
sql = """
WITH r AS ( SELECT m.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY word ORDER BY freq DESC) AS rn FROM raw_words AS m)
INSERT INTO preprocessed_words(word, pos, lemma, freq) SELECT r.word, r.pos, r.lemma, r.freq FROM r where r.rn=1
"""
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('postgresql://'+username+':'+password+'@'+hostname + ':' + port + '/'+database)
connection = engine.connect()
connection.execute(sql)
```

my table `preprocess_words` results emtpy. If I try simple script like:

```
    sql = """INSERT INTO preprocessed_words(word, pos, lemma, freq) VALUES ('word', 'pos', 'lemma', 0);"""
```

it works.
I also tried updating sqlalchemy but to no avail.

I need sqlalchemy, because I use pandas `to_sql` with sqlalchemy engine. I also do table insert inside sql database, because there are a lot of data.

What I am missing?

Comment: You're having the same issue as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347565/executing-multiple-statements-with-postgresql-via-sqlalchemy-does-not-persist-ch, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376142/teradata-merge-yielding-no-results-when-executed-through-sqlalchemy

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561894/calling-stored-function-or-procedure-wont-insert-and-persist-changes