# Comment on Table does not commit

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

When executing a comment on a table like below , it seems to never commit.

Looking at engine logging i cannot see the COMMIT execution.

```
# adding comment to table with creation date.
engine.execute("COMMENT ON TABLE can.src_add_lookup IS 'Table create date: {}';".format(datetime.utcnow()))
engine.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE can.src_add_lookup")
```

Execution logs

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:**COMMIT**
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_add_5b45adb005ee4da6b32ed0421df9314b ON can.src_add_lookup (id)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:**COMMIT**
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:COMMENT ON TABLE can.src_add_lookup IS 'Table create date: 2019-03-11 14:37:49.843897';
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:TRUNCATE TABLE can.src_add_lookup
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:**COMMIT**
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347565/executing-multiple-statements-with-postgresql-via-sqlalchemy-does-not-persist-ch, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42376142/teradata-merge-yielding-no-results-when-executed-through-sqlalchemy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561894/calling-stored-function-or-procedure-wont-insert-and-persist-changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after going over the related links on the Ilja Everilä got this working like below.

```
# adding comment to table with creation date.
comment = sqlalchemy.text("COMMENT ON TABLE {}.src_add_lookup IS 'Table create date: {}';".format(schema, datetime.utcnow())).execution_options(autocommit=True)
engine.execute(comment)
```